"She smiles in a way that makes him even more uncomfortable."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 27)

Before the play; Imogen making William up


'What are you doing to me?'
'Making you look like a woman, what do you think I'm doing?' she's enjoying his consternation and he decides to milk it.
'My mum'd have a fit,' he says, but instantly regrets it. He doesn't want Imogen to think his family prudish, so adds, 'Though Uncle Robert and Howard would love it,' and then regrets that too.
'Who's Howard?'
William feels the rise of a flush to his face. 'Part of the family business.'
'And a good friend of your uncle's?' She smiles in a way that makes him even more uncomfortable.

I suspect this clause in question to be a bit sloppy English. I'm missing the verb 'feel': (the whole sentence) 'She smiles in a way that makes him feel even more uncomfortable'. On the other hand I see that using the wording 'that makes him even more uncomfortable' is also possible almost having the same meaning because 'uncomfortable' can mean "uneasy, troubled, disturbed, embarrassed" Collins. In summary, I don't see much difference between 'make someone feel uncomfortable' and 'make someone uncomfortable'.

I'm confused; the question seems to start out saying "don't we need 'feel'?" and end up (rightly) saying "I guess we don't." Can you make the question clearer?

Nothing wrong with the English there.  The raptor circling overhead made the squirrels nervous. Her questions made him uncomfortable.

Note: Many emotions and sensations are also states of being, so "it makes me X" is usually fine: "That ad made me hungry," "her snub made me jealous," "the movie made me sad." But note that there can be fine shades of meaning between "I am angry" and "I feel angry." Qualifying it with "feel" might emphasize the state as temporary and distanced from the person's identity.

"I suspect this clause in question to be a bit sloppy English" is 100% wrong! (though I can't say the same about the sentence I've just quoted, which no native Anglophone would ever say or write). Your source isn't exactly great literature, but the writer knows English perfectly well. If you're going to end up suspecting it actually contains incorrect text, perhaps you shouldn't be reading it in the first place!

Something makes me feel uncomfortable. Something else makes me feel even more uncomfortable. What is your issue? It's is not necessary to say: makes me feel more uncomfortable.  That writer chose not to say it like that.

Bravo, @FumbleFingers!

@FumbleFingers - ". . . which no native Anglophone would ever say or write" - Then, please tell me how I can amend this sentence so that the native speaker would be content with. Thank you very much in advance; of course I have to learn very much :)

"a bit sloppy" can't be used attributively (before the noun it modifies, English here). It can only be used predicatively. as in His English is a bit sloppy. I'm not sure what the rule is there, since "rather sloppy" works both ways. Perhaps it's whenever the adverbial starts with an indefinite article. I expect someone would know, if you wanted to ask as a formal question (here or maybe on ELU; it should be ok there).

Why has this question been downvoted? I don't understand that.

Dear moderators, please tell me why this question has been downvoted. I want to know what is wrong with this question.

I'd delete both the comments in bold,  you have a received an answer from a moderator, so you should have a better idea why the question attracted DVs

There really is no difference in this case, because the state of feeling uncomfortable and the state of being uncomfortable are essentially the same thing - with a completely internal feeling like this, how you feel is how you are. There is basically no difference between feeling uncomfortable and being uncomfortable - I can't think of any way that one could feel uncomfortable without being uncomfortable, or be uncomfortable without feeling it.
There could be shades of meaning in cases where the way the person feels may not align with how they actually are, like if the sentence dealt with the feeling of being "out of place" - she could smile in a way that makes him feel out of place, but she probably couldn't smile in a way that actually makes him be out of place. One could conceivably feel out of place without actually being out of place (or vice versa), so there would be some difference in this case - the sentence would probably have to be "She smiles in a way that makes him feel even more out of place."
